# SQL Server suspended queries - tempDb pagelatch_up 2:1:2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have performance issue on MS SQL 2014 db.
Store procedure that does SELECT has input parameters as custom Table Value Parameter type.
There are 50-100 sessions at the time and executing store proc can take 1s to 14s.
I can execute SP with simple input parameter and it can take 1s if I repeat the same it can take up to 14s, it almost if I am feeling lucky or not.

Running diagnostic queries I can see PAGELATCH_UP on many calls to this store procedure and there is a chain of one session id waiting on another session id.
PAGELATCH_UP is in the format of resource 2:1:2 2:6:2 2:9:2 depends from the time of capture.
So 2:: is tempDb :1: or :6: are tempDb files, there is 8 of them and this is 128GB 32core machine.
For the last one ::2 I could found out it is Global Allocation Map (GAM).

In all blogs people have usually have issue with resource ::1 or ::3 (PFS and SGAM), but haven't seen anything regarding GAM.

There is a recommendation from Microsoft how to resolve contention in tempDB which focuses on PFS and SGAM:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2154845/recommendations-to-reduce-allocation-contention-in-sql-server-tempdb-d

Would you suggest increasing number of tempDb files from 8 to 12, 16, ...32?
Is it issue with table-valued parameters, and this is the reason for pagelatch_up as this is select statement in SP?
Any other replacement for Table Value Parameters?

Comment: I think it might help. what is the drive type? if its in azure try to use E-family before spliting it

Answer (score 1):

**Is it an issue with table-valued parameters, and this is the reason for pagelatch_up as this is a select statement in SP?**

Table-valued parameters create an activity on the tempdb database
for this reason, your stored procedure might be caused to [tempdb allocation contention](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-27-of-30-troubleshooting-tempdb-contention/).
The main symptoms of this issue is to see the following wait types in the tempdb database;

- PAGELATCH_UP
- PAGELATCH_SH
- PAGELATCH_EX

In general, you can solve this problem to create multiple tempdb data files because of the
your SQL Server version you might be used to
-[T1117 and -T1118 flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-t1117-and-t1118-changes-for-tempdb-and-user-databases).

**Any other replacement for Table Value Parameters?**

On the other hand, using the Memory-Optimized Table Variables can solve this type of problems
using the [Memory-Optimized Table Types and Table Variables](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2014/01/07/sql-server-2014-in-memory-oltp-memory-optimized-table-types-and-table-variables/)

**Would you suggest increasing the number of tempDb files from 8 to 12, 16, ...32?**

This is the best practice:

*The number of the TempDB data files should match the number of logical processors, up to eight files, on the machine where the SQL Server instance is installed.*

However, this value can change according to your requirements.